# LINQ:Select Newest From Each Group

Tags: c#, linq

So, I know I'm very rusty, but I never thought this would be so difficult in spite of spending hours trying different solutions.  I'm trying to select the newest record from each group, after eliminating a particular clause and then binding it to a grid.  Having essentially no luck... this is where I left off:

```
var widgets = db.Updates
            .GroupBy(c => c.widgetType)
            .SelectMany(s => s)
            .Where(c => c.Sold.Equals(false))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        var list = new List<Update>() {widgets};
            widgetsGrid.DataSource = list;            
            widgetsGrid.DataBind();
```

I added the cast to list since I was getting a data type error, and at present it returns only the last item of all records, rather than the last item from each group.

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OrderByDescending` should be on the level of each group. You also don't need `SelectMany` because this will join the groups back into a flat list.

```
var widgets = Updates
        .GroupBy(c => c.widgetType)
        .Where(c => c.Sold.Equals(false))
        .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp).First());
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Ahmad Ibrahim... but still doesn't work.  When I run your code as you have it, I again get a data type exception, so I added a "ToList" and still get only the last record, rather than the last of each group. I now have: 

var widgets = db.Updates
        .GroupBy(c => c.widgetType)
        .Where(c => c.Sold.Equals(false))
        .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp).First());
var list = new List<Update>(){widgets};

Comment: `var list = widgets.ToList()` should work well.. you cannot use `new List<Update> {widgets};`

Comment: Thanks again, @Ahmad ... I'm very grateful butttttttttttt... I've tried using ToList() and I get an "unknown method" error, which I seem to recall reading is an idiosyncracy of LINQ in this scenario.  

I would never have believed this is so hard to implement :(

Comment: And the List issue aside... when I look at the results from the query, it's only selecting one record :(

Ugh,,,

Comment: @PaulBerendsohn check this working fiddle please https://ideone.com/oiO7ro

Comment: !!! You're so close I can taste victory! ;)  Thank you thank you!!!  One lasttttttttttttt little tweak,  we lost the "where: clause and when I insert it like so:
.GroupBy(c => c.widgetType)
.Where(c => c.Sold.Equals(false))
etc etc 

I get an exception... :(

Don't give up on me now ;)

Comment: Winner winner, chicken dinner!  I moved the where clause to the beginning and it seems to run fine!

@Ahmad Ibrahim... thank you very very much!  I can't tell you how much I appreciate your time and effort... seriously, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
         var widgets = db.Updates
        .GroupBy(c => c.widgetType)
        .SelectMany(s => s)
        .Where(c => c.Sold.Equals(false))
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp)
        .Select(y=>y.First());

    var list = new List<Update>() {widgets};
        widgetsGrid.DataSource = list;            
        widgetsGrid.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the key thing you need to do is order by and select the first item from the list. Here's an example program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foodOrders = new List<FoodOrder>
        {
            new FoodOrder { FoodName = "hotdog", OrderDate = new DateTime(2016, 7, 7) },
            new FoodOrder { FoodName = "hamburger", OrderDate = new DateTime(2016, 7, 6) },
            new FoodOrder { FoodName = "taco", OrderDate = new DateTime(2016, 7, 5) },
        };

        var mostRecentFoodOrder = foodOrders.OrderByDescending(f => f.OrderDate).First().FoodName;
        Console.WriteLine(mostRecentFoodOrder);

        //cmd
        //hotdog
        //Press any key to continue . . .
    }
}

class FoodOrder
{
    public string FoodName { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var widgets = db.Updates
          .Where(c => c.Sold.Equals(false))
          .GroupBy(c => c.widgetType)       
      .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp).First()).ToList();
       widgetGrid.DataSource = widgets;
       widgetGrid.DataBind();
```

I've seen this question asked a hundred times all over the web... this worked for me.  Courtesy of, and many thanks to @Ahmad Ibrahim

Comment: @Ahmad Ibrahim If I haven't completely worn out my welcome (I hope) ... Now that this basic functionality works, I find I need to add a join (or two).  Could I ask you if you'd be kind enough to show me an example of adding one to this?

Many manyyyyyyyyyyy thanks!